# TensorFlow getting elements of every row for specific columns

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

If `A` is a TensorFlow variable like so

```
A = tf.Variable([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
```

and `index` is another variable

```
index = tf.Variable([0, 1])
```

I want to use this index to select columns in each row. In this case, item 0 from first row and item 1 from second row.

If A was a Numpy array then to get the columns of corresponding rows mentioned in index we can do

```
x = A[np.arange(A.shape[0]), index]
```

and the result would be

```
[1, 4]
```

What is the TensorFlow equivalent operation/operations for this? I know TensorFlow doesn't support many indexing operations. What would be the work around if it cannot be done directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After dabbling around for quite a while. I found two functions that could be useful.

One is `tf.gather_nd()` which might be useful if you can produce a tensor 
of the form `[[0, 0], [1, 1]]` and thereby you could do

`index = tf.constant([[0, 0], [1, 1]])`

`tf.gather_nd(A, index)`

If you are unable to produce a vector of the form `[[0, 0], [1, 1]]`(I couldn't produce this as the number of rows in my case was dependent on a placeholder) for some reason then the work around I found is to use the `tf.py_func()`. Here is an example code on how this can be done

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import numpy as np 

def index_along_every_row(array, index):
    N, _ = array.shape 
    return array[np.arange(N), index]

a = tf.Variable([[1, 2], [3, 4]], dtype=tf.int32)
index = tf.Variable([0, 1], dtype=tf.int32)
a_slice_op = tf.py_func(index_along_every_row, [a, index], [tf.int32])[0]
session = tf.InteractiveSession()

a.initializer.run()
index.initializer.run()
a_slice = a_slice_op.eval()
```

`a_slice` will be a numpy array `[1, 4]`

Answer (score 10):

You can extend your column indices with row indices and then use gather_nd:

```
import tensorflow as tf

A = tf.constant([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
indices = tf.constant([1, 0])

# prepare row indices
row_indices = tf.range(tf.shape(indices)[0])

# zip row indices with column indices
full_indices = tf.stack([row_indices, indices], axis=1)

# retrieve values by indices
S = tf.gather_nd(A, full_indices)

session = tf.InteractiveSession()
session.run(S)
```

Comment: Hi, your answer is great, here I wonder what if then the row size is unknown, for example in batch?

Answer (score 8):

You can use [one hot](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/one_hot) method to create a one_hot array and use it as a boolean mask to select the indices you'd like.

```
A = tf.Variable([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
index = tf.Variable([0, 1])

one_hot_mask = tf.one_hot(index, A.shape[1], on_value = True, off_value = False, dtype = tf.bool)
output = tf.boolean_mask(A, one_hot_mask)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do the same using this combination of `map_fn` and `gather_nd`.

```
def get_element(a, indices):
    """
    Outputs (ith element of indices) from (ith row of a)
    """
    return tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.gather_nd(x[0], x[1]), 
                                  (a, indices),
                                  dtype = tf.float32)
```

Here's an example usage.

```
A = tf.constant(np.array([[1,2,3],
                          [4,5,6],
                          [7,8,9]], dtype = np.float32))

idx = tf.constant(np.array([[2],[1],[0]]))
elems = get_element(A, idx)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    e = sess.run(elems)

print(e)
```

I don't know if this will be much slower than other answers.

It has the advantage that you don't need to specify the number of rows of A in advance, as long as `a` and `indices` have the same number of rows at runtime.

Note the output of the above will be rank 1. If you'd prefer it to have rank 2, replace `gather_nd` by `gather`

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the accepted answer to work in Tensorflow 2 when I incorporated it into a loss function. Something about GradientTape didn't like it. My solution is an altered version of the accepted answer:

```
def get_rows(arr):
  N, _ = arr.shape 
  return N

num_rows= tf.py_function(get_rows, [arr], [tf.int32])[0]
rng = tf.range(0,num_rows)
ind = tf.stack([rng, ind], axis=1)
tf.gather_nd(arr, ind)
```